# Javascript in browser address string - problem with form submit

Tags: javascript, submit

I try to write inline javascript for [visa state checking](https://www.vfsglobal.org/ukg-passporttracking/ApplicantTrackStatus.aspx?Data=YzLYMFd3w3LznOCbxa6ahQ==)

This is my code

```
javascript:document.getElementById("txtRefNO").value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";document.getElementById("txtDat").value="dd";document.getElementById("txtMont").value="mm";document.getElementById("txtYea").value="yyyy";setTimeout('document.getElementById("form1").submit()',5000);void(0);
```

This script fill filds and jast reload page. But when i click on submit button it's ok.
What the difference between clicking and submit() calling?

Comment: "It's ok"? You haven't explained very well the different behaviours that you expect and the behaviours that you observe. You also haven't provided any context at all for your code. And what is `void(0);` supposed to achieve?

Comment: In general, this should work. Did you test it, e.g. by creating some button that calls the submit function? Like this: `<span onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">submit</span>`

Comment: I try to execute this code from browser address string, i can't add element on page. Without void(0) browser redirect to empty page.

Comment: Please show some html code - where and when are you calling the function? Why does your function load an empty page?

Comment: I open page(you can try with any page, e.g. google.com) and write into url field in browser expression like "javascript:alert('blablabla');" ant it's execute. Sorry for my eng)

Comment: Which of my questions did you answer? If I type `javascript:alert('blablabla');` into the address bar, it alerts 'blablabla' but doesn't reload the page. And your provided code doesn't look like you are calling it from the address bar. So, please edit your question and add your html code there...

Comment: Try on google.com this: "javascript: document.getElementById('hplogo').style.background='none';void(0);" with and without void(0)

Comment: @Martin: Actually the original code seemed to be valid to me - it began with `javascript:` and my browser at least, newlines were ignored and the script ran as it should've.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the *What the difference between clicking and submit() calling?*, in this case when you click the button, the form submits with an extra parameter `cmdSubmit` with the value `Submit` - this is the submit button and the text you see on it. The server side component for this page may very well be looking for this parameter in order to validate the submitted form (perhaps not the best approach).

Try this instead - note that I've changed it from a call to `submit()` on the form to a `click()` on the submit button

```
javascript:document.getElementById("txtRefNO").value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";document.getElementById("txtDat").value="dd";document.getElementById("txtMont").value="mm";document.getElementById("txtYea").value="yyyy";setTimeout('document.getElementById("cmdSubmit").click()',5000);void(0);
```